# Android - How to start an application on the /sdcard after boot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sd-card, boot

Is there a way how to start and android application after a boot automatically if it is on the `/sdcard`?

Ok, probably by `BroadcastReceiver`. But which action is the right one?

```
ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED - does not work if it is on the /sdcard (documented)
ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED - does not work if it is on the /sdcard (which is undocumented)
ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE - does not work, I do not know why
ACTION_USER_PRESENT - does not work if the BroadcastReceiver is registered in AndroidManifest (which is undocumented, but documentation bug has been reported)
```

Thanks
Jan

Comment: did you ever solve this? I've got a similar problem now.

Comment: Your question helped me find my answer, thanks. :D

Comment: If you find it helpful, you should accept the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid the only correct answer to this question is: No, there is no way.

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248617/run-a-service-when-device-starts-after-sd-finishes-loading answers this problem correctly which is to create a receiver for both `BOOT_COMPLETED` and `MEDIA_MOUNTED`

Answer (score 1):

Please mention it in manifest file.

```
</uses-permission>    
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

provide permission "android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" as child of menifest.

and one more thing your app must not be installed in sdcard.

Comment: This does not answer the question because the question specifically asked how to be notified at boot when the app *is* installed on the SD card.

Comment: I am not sure but it's not possible according to me.

Comment: I agree, so the right answer is that it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

try using `<receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

and this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

perhaps QUICKBOOT_POWERON help u

Answer (score 1):

According to Google, you should not put any app you want to run at boot on an external drive.

"The system delivers the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast before the external storage is mounted to the device. If your application is installed on the external storage, it can never receive this broadcast."

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html#ShouldNot

Answer (score 0):

I usually register every intent filter for a broadcast receiver both ways (Android Manifest as well as dynamically in a class that extends Application)

In AndroidManifest.xml as:

```
    <receiver
            android:name=".broadcastReciever"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and in a class that extends Application:

```
registerReceiver(new broadcastReciever(), new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE));
```

and don't forget to add `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission and register the class which extends Application in the Android Manifest.

This should do; feel free to ask for any more help/clarification.

Comment: Huh why both ways?